# Contar registros y agruparlos en una sola columna de 2 tablas MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo 2 tablas de la siguiente manera:

productos:

| id | clave | minimo | reorden | maximo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | new1 | 10 | 15 | 20 |
| 2 | new2 | 20 | 30 | 40 |
| 3 | new3 | 50 | 100 | 200 |

almacén:

| id | clave | piezas |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | new1 | 15 |
| 2 | new1 | 10 |
| 3 | new2 | 17 |
| 4 | new2 | 20 |

el resultado al que quiero llegar es que me muestre algo así:

| excedido |
| --- |
| 1 |

ya que en el ejemplo anterior new1 en la tabla almacén sumado tiene 25, mientras que en la tabla productos el máximo es 20, es decir, new1 excede lo establecido en la columna máximo de la tabla productos.

Estoy batallando con la consulta para que me el resultado que busco, tengo la siguiente:

```
SELECT one.maximo, COUNT(one.clave) AS excedido FROM
productos AS one LEFT JOIN almacen AS two using(clave)
GROUP BY one.clave HAVING COALESCE(SUM(two.piezas),0) >
one.maximo;
```

Lo que me da como resultado:

| maximo | excedido |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 2 |

1 row in set

Vi el siguiente [link](https:////es.stackoverflow.com/questions/114671/c%C3%B3mo-sumar-y-agrupar-por-medio-de-condiciones-en-mysql) en el cual usan solo 1 tabla, como podría hacerlo funcional para 2 tablas?

Comment: Busca la clausula HAVING

Comment: @Luis Cazares Ya revise la clausula HAVING, edite la pregunta, alguna idea al respecto?